# Netbeans - Automatic Java ME SDK platform addition failing

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am trying to setup Java ME SDK 8.3 with Netbeans 8.2. I followed the following install order:

- Java SE Development Kit 8u152
- Java ME SDK 8.3
- Netbeans 8.2

Then I try to add Java ME SDK 8.3 to Java Platforms

Tools --> Java Platforms --> Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator --> Choose Java ME SDK Directory, then automatic detection fails.

[image: Selecting Java ME SDK Folder]

[image: Adding Java ME SDK]

[image: Automatic Detection of Java ME SDK Fails]

I have tried re-installing Java ME SDK and Netbeans. But it didn't help. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SDK 8.3 isn't CLDC but rather CDC.
A lot of people are confused by this, which is understandable. I have no clue why Oracle thought it was a good idea to keep the name "JavaME SDK" but leave out MIDP and CLDC starting from version 8.

What you need to download is Java ME SDK 3.4 (or the latest v3.x). This is the last Java ME SDK that contains CLDC API's.

Comment: But, even after I choose Java ME CDC Platform Manager, It didn't work. After choosing the Java ME SDK folder, the Next button doesn't get enabled.

Comment: Try download JavaME SDK 3.4. That's the one you need for MIDlet development. 8.x is for Xlet development.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add the path for your Java SDK in the **netbeans.conf** file.

Right-click on your desktop and click properties and open location:

1. Open Dir **C:\Program Files\NetBeans-15\netbeans\etc**
2. Open File **netbeans.conf**

goto

```
 # Default location of JDK:
 # (set by installer or commented out if launcher should decide)
 #
 # It can be overridden on command line by using --jdkhome <dir>
 # Be careful when changing jdkhome.
 # There are two NetBeans launchers for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and
 # installer points to one of those in the NetBeans application shortcut 
 # based on the Java version selected at installation time.
```

netbeans_jdkhome="PATH TO YOUR SDK"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. Installing Sun Java Wireless Toolkit worked for me.

Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html